# How to get the values of the radiobuttonlist which will be selected in nested datalist to use it in multi insert later using c# asp.net 2

Tags: c#-2.0, datalist

How to get the values of the `radiobuttonlist` which will be selected in nested datalist to use it in multi insert later.
I want to get all the values of the controls of the `radiobuttonlist` to use them in multi insert statement in my code.

Comment: It would help if you'd specify at least what language and GUI toolkit you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

$("#<%=rbl.ClientID%> input:checked").val()